# Bar Chart that spans dates on x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

Is there a matplotlib or other library that would create bars that span dates on the x-axis? Sample table:

```
Start Date  End Date    Number
1/4/2017    1/11/2017   7
1/12/2017   1/18/2017   3
1/20/2017   1/23/2017   5
1/27/2017   1/30/2017   5
2/7/2017    3/1/2017    12
```

I would like a bar for each line in the table. The first bar would start on 1/4/2017 and span to 1/11/2017 with a height of 7, and so on for each row.

I tried using two values in for x, but errored with "only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars."

I tried counting the number of days between the dates and using that as the Width of the bar, but the middle of the bar is placed on the Start Date.

I can't find a method or pre-configured chart that would graph these kind of bars.

Comment: I think you could manipulate your data into a histogram format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've tried to use the `width=` parameter, you were pretty close. Looks like you were only missing the [`align='edge'` parameter to have the bar start at the correct date](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html?highlight=matplotlib%20pyplot%20bar#matplotlib.pyplot.bar).

```
ax.bar(df.loc[:,'Start Date'].values, df.loc[:,'Number'], width=[7,6,3,3,22], align='edge')
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, I tired 'left' or 'right' but not 'edge'. That did the trick, Thanks!